# logic: equal with the contents of a hidden field

Tags: java, jsp, struts, jsp-tags, hidden-field

I have a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="champs" id="champs">
```

I want do a `<logic:equal>` with the content of this field hidden, I tried the solutions but not work

```
<logic:equal name="virement" property="statut"  value='champs' >
```

just be there is a syntax very precise in the value property of the logic: equal that I can found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little rusty with this, but here are some hints:

Your field "champs" is a browser field, not a Java variable. When your request arrives at your servlet, the contents of browser fields have been transferred to request parameters. So the value in your field will end up in a predefined object called `request`, and for convenience broken down some more in a bean called `param`. There's a syntax for accessing this stuff... see below.

A little more detail (though I've seen it explained better) can be found in [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) and maybe [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/Servlets7.html#wp64433). Better yet, [here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tutorials/jsp20/simpleel.html)

You can Google for "JSP Expression Language" to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the struts tag `html:hidden` instead of input `type = "hidden"`